# convert pixel values into RGB format

Tags: java

I a have the red, green and blue values of a pixel seperately. How to convert them into RBG format to create a new image? I basically need a reverse process for this:

```
int red = (rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
int green = (rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
int blue = rgb & 0xFF;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int rgb = ((r << 16) | ((g << 8) | b);
```

assuming it's RGB888. Make sure `r,g and b` are all in the 0-255 range

Answer (score 0):

It's a great practice to use the `java.awt.Color` class instead.
It will make the things **simpler** and **easier**. In your case it would be:

```
Color myColor = new Color(red, green, blue); //Construct the color
myColor.getRGB(); //Get the RGB of the constructed color
```

Or the inverse:

```
Color myColor = new Color(rgb); //Construct the color with the RGB value
myColor.getRed(); //Get the separate components of the constructed color
myColor.getGreen();
myColor.getBlue();
```

*For more info, consult the [Javadocs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html).*